# MongoDB: What's the point of using MapReduce without parallelism?

Tags: parallel-processing, mongodb, mapreduce

Quoting http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce#MapReduce-Parallelism

> As of right now, MapReduce jobs on a
>   single mongod process are single
>   threaded. This is due to a design
>   limitation in current JavaScript
>   engines. We are looking into
>   alternatives to solve this issue, but
>   for now if you want to parallelize
>   your MapReduce jobs, you will need to
>   either use sharding or do the
>   aggregation client-side in your code.

Without parallelism, what are the benefits of MapReduce compared to simpler or more traditional methods for queries and data aggregation?

To avoid confusion: the question is NOT "what are the benefits of document-oriented DB over traditional relational DB"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The main reason to use MapReduce over simpler or more traditional queries is that it simply can do things (i.e., aggregation) that simple queries cannot.

Once you need aggregation, there are two options using MongoDB: MapReduce and the group command.  The group command is analogous to SQL's "group by" and is limited in that it has to return all its results in a single database response.  That means group can only be used when you have less than 4MB of results.  MapReduce, on the other hand, can do anything a "group by" can, but outputs results to a new collection so results can be as large as needed.

Also, parallelism is coming, so it's good to have some practice :)

Comment: What version will get parallelism?

Comment: any update on JS engine for mongodb mapReduce ? Does it provide parallelism now?

Answer (score 4):

M/R is already parallel in MongoDB if you're running a sharded cluster. This is the main point of M/R anyway - to put the computation on the same node as the data.

Comment: Am I right in assuming, that the current way of taking advantage of a multi-core computer is by running multiple MongoDB instances on the same machine?

Answer (score 1):

super fast map/reduce is on the roadmap

it will not be in the 1.6 release (summer release)

so late this year likely